# SQLite DB won't update when running PHP script from cron

Tags: php, sqlite, cron, command-line-interface

I cannot update a SQLite DB when running the PHP script from my crontab.

When I just open example.com/app.php in my browser, it works fine. Same when I run

```
php -q /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/app.php
```

But my crontab

```
*/5 * * * * php -q /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/app.php >> /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/log/monitor.log 2>&1
```

won't update the SQLite DB. I have implemented a file log (at the end of my file) as well, and it gets written every run. So the crontab runs and seems to be working. The cron log is empty.

I have verified that SQLite is enabled with:

```
php -a if(class_exists('SQLite3')) echo 'ok';
```

The directory and the DB file itself are both rwxrwxrwx.

Any ideas? Why is it working, running the script directly from CLI but not from within the crontab? The only difference should be the user, but permissions are set to 777. So I cannot see where the problem is.

Server is AWS Lightsail with PHP 7.3

===

EDIT: Crontab is of user bitnami

Comment: Debugging cron can be a little tricky.  The log file you have is for output from the php script.  You should also check the cron log at `/var/log/cron` and I would run it without the `-q` until you get it working.  You should also turn on all error output in the php file until you get it working too, via `error_reporting(E_ALL);`  If your php script depends on http at all, you will have to change it so that it doesn't.

Comment: Thanks! /var/log/cron doesn't exist. PHP error_reporting was enabled. Removing -q option hasn't changed anything :(

Comment: The cron is run as the root user, so try running it on the command line as root and see if there are any errors: `sudo php /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/app.php`

Comment: Don't know why, but it works now as I put it into the root crontab. Guess, there is something off with my permissions. Anyhow, I leave it in root's crontab :) Thanks for your help!!